# Unable to deploy simple flask app to azure web app

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, flask-restful

I'm trying to deploy a very simple flask app to linux azure web app, but it seems like it cannot find any of the packages installed

it works on localhost using a virtual env

Here is the app code that is on folder startup.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

class Index(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return "Hellow World"

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Index, "/home")
```

I'm trying to deploy the app using azure DevOps pipelines, here is my azure-pipeline.yml file (I removed the variables for this post)

```
variables:
  ConnectedServiceName: <name of my service connection>
  WebAppName: <name of my web app>


pool:
  name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.6'
    architecture: 'x64'

- script: pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install requirements'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Application$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
    #verbose: # (no value); this input is optional

- task: AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: Azure App Service Deploy
  inputs:
    appType: webAppLinux
    RuntimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.6'
    ConnectedServiceName: $(ConnectedServiceName)
    WebAppName: $(WebAppName)
    Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Application$(Build.BuildId).zip'

    StartupCommand: 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --workers=4 startup:app'
```

and this is my requirements.txt file

```
aniso8601==7.0.0
astroid==2.2.5
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.1
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-JWT-Extended==3.22.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.7
flask-swagger-ui==3.20.9
```

The pipelines runs all the steps without error
[Deployment Image](https://pasteboard.co/IvRv60N.png)

but it seems like there are no packages in wwwroot folder

```
/home>cd site/wwwroot
/home/site/wwwroot>pip freeze
virtualenv==16.6.2
/home/site/wwwroot>
```

Also tried `pip install -r requirements.txt` standing at this folder, it collects the packages but nevers ends to install them (it show "Cleaning up...>" for ever)

On the application logs I can see

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful'
2019-09-04T14:55:19.215300670Z [2019-09-04 14:55:19 +0000] [39] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 39)
2019-09-04T14:55:19.234394151Z [2019-09-04 14:55:19 +0000] [38] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
```

How can I make sure that the web app uses the packages listed in the requirements.txt

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you share how you upload your code, I want to see your local code structure

Answer (score 0):

Tried to create a sample pipeline -

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.6'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 3.6

- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'Run a Python script'
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: 'pip install -r req.txt'
  enabled: false

- script: 'pip install -r req.txt --target=$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
  inputs:
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.BinariesDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ''
    appType: webAppLinux
    appName: 
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.6'
```

PublishBuildArtifacts - is not required here but can be used to verify the actual build artifact that will be published to webapp. You can try and verify whether the packages are present in the artifacts or not.

Comment: could you please provide more details on it? Tried changing Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory to Build.DefaultWorkingDirectory and not working, also tried to add at the end of file - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1